# Logging with Winston in Express.js - how to configure for different environments?

Tags: node.js, logging, express, winston

I've started to use [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) for logging errors and events with my node/express.js app.

One thing I have not figured out is how to specify different Winston transports (or other config) for different environments (Dev/Test/Production).  E.g. I want to have everything logged to the console in the dev enviroment, but use a different transport in Production.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no "standard" way to do this, but you might do something like this:

```
var myLogTransports = [];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
  myLogTransports.push(new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'somefile.log' }));
}
else {
  myLogTransports.push(new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: 'error' })));
}

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: myLogTransports,
});
```

Winston now supports adding loggers dynamically. See the [Working with Transports](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#working-with-transports) section for more information. The original answer could be rewritten like this:

```
var logger = new winston.Logger();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
  logger.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'somefile.log' });
}
else {
  logger.add(winston.transports.Console, { level: 'error' });
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks.  I haven't been using process.env to date in my JS code, but I guess this is the same parameter that  e.g. `app.configure('development', function(){...});` is reacting to?

Comment: Yeah, `app.configure('development', function(){...});` is Express' way of checking the environment setting. For this to work, you need to set `NODE_ENV=production` when you're running Express live, but you should be doing this already, as Express will otherwise run a lot slower.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that already, but wasn't sure if `app.configure(...` / `process.env` were referring to the same variable.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it might as well be as close to real world code as possible :)